# How to make a scrollable JList to add details got from a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jlist, joptionpane, scrollable

I want to repeatedly take input from the user(probably using a button) via a JOptionPane(already done) and store the details in something(how about a dynamic object array) and display this information as a list in a scrollable JList.

---

MY CODE

---

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class Flight {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 2,20, 20));

    //Add textfields here
    JTextField txtflightno = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtmechanicalstatus = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtmedicalstatus = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtfuellevel = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtweathercondition = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtfrequency = new JTextField(8);
    JTextField txtflightpath = new JTextField(8);






    //Add labels here
    JLabel lblflightno = new JLabel("Flight No : ");
    JLabel lblmechanicalstatus = new JLabel("Mechanical Status:");
    JLabel lblmedicalstatus = new JLabel("Medical Status:");
    JLabel lblfuellevel = new JLabel("Fuel Level:");
    JLabel lblweathercondition = new JLabel("Weather Condition:");
    JLabel lblfrequency = new JLabel("Frequency:");
    JLabel lblflightpath = new JLabel("Flight Path:");





    //Adding flightno to panel
    panel.add(lblflightno);
    panel.add(txtflightno);

    //Adding mechanicalstatus to the panel
    panel.add(lblmechanicalstatus);
    panel.add(txtmechanicalstatus);

    //Adding medicalstatus to the panel
    panel.add(lblmedicalstatus);
    panel.add(txtmedicalstatus);

    //Adding fuellevel to the panel
    panel.add(lblfuellevel);
    panel.add(txtfuellevel);

    //Adding weathercondition to the panel
    panel.add(lblweathercondition);
    panel.add(txtweathercondition);

    //Adding frequency to the panel
    panel.add(lblfrequency);
    panel.add(txtfrequency);

    //Adding flightpath to the panel
    panel.add(lblflightpath);
    panel.add(txtflightpath);


    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);




   int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Flight Details",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

    }
}
}
```

---

How must I do the storing of the plane details ? How must I implement a scrollable JList ? Any suggestions.

Many Thanks

Comment: You've got some good answers here, so you should mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 11):

As discussed in [*How to Use Lists*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), `JList` uses a list model as the source of data it displays. Just add your data to a [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), and use it to construct your list.

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
// add data
JList list = new JList(dlm);
panel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
```

Answer (score 4):

To make the JList scrollable, simply embed it in a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html). Instead of

```
add(myList, constraints);
```

do

```
add(new JScrollPane(myList), constraints);
```

To extend the list, just get the JList's ListModel (using `getListModel`) and use `add` to add objects.

More on using ListModels [in Sun's tutorial](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MWPPw-9QqMkJ:java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html+defaultlistmodel&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de&lr=lang_nl|lang_en&client=firefox-a).

More on ScrollPane [in the Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), too.

Comment: you mean `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 0):

You've to use the `ActionListener` of Button, that you've missed in the code snippet.

In the OK Option :

```
JList jlist = ...;

jlist.add(txtflightno.getText());
jlist.add(txtmechanicalstatus.getText());
jlist.add(txtmedicalstatus.getText());
....
....

& 

add(new JScrollPanel(myList), constraints);
```

After this use validate method of Component to update the list with this new item.
But one thing you should remember is that list displays each item row-wise. 
I suggest you to use [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with which you can display your items in a meaningful way...

Comment: coder: I don't see where @Haxed needs an `ActionListener`; the `JOptionPane`'s OK button should do. Also, `JList` can't accept data directly; a `ListModel` should be used instead.